# Are there methods of filtering gps-data with metadata?

Tags: postgis, gps, metadata, filter, nmea

In our project we captured GPS-tracks from a few electric vehicles in the timeframe of a year. In total we captured around 13000000 GPS-points this way. The captured data comes from electric powered cars and we gathered some information from the car as well(power output, average loading time, speed, gear shift, brake state, ...). The Gps-points and the other information is not synchronized. We need a way to filter both the information and the gps so that we can figure out, for example the average output for a part of the road. The data looks something like this:

GPS:

lat1,long1,timepoint1
lat2,long2,timepoint2
lat3,long3,timepoint3

(encoded in NMEA)

Power output:

ev_power1.1,timpoint1.1
ev_power1.2,timpoint1.2
ev_power1.3,timpoint1.3
...
ev_power2.1,timpoint2.1
ev_power2.2,timpoint2.2
ev_power2.3,timpoint2.3
...
ev_power3.1,timpoint3.1
ev_power3.2,timpoint3.2
ev_power3.3,timpoint3.3
...

where timepoints 1.1-1.n are somwehere between timepoint1 and timepoint2.

The final output should look something like this:

lat1',long1',ev_power1',1timepoint1'
lat2',long2',ev_power2',timepoint2'

After the Filtering we want to write it in our Postgis database. We hope to reduce the scattering of our data without losing too much of our extra information. Does anybody have a list of methods I could look into?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! Can you please *edit* your question and be more specific what your desired outcome is, especially what you mean by a reduction of scattering without affecting the metadata?

Comment: Does __each__ track point have associated data, or is it summarised for track segments? If it's for each track point individually, sounds like the 'metadata' is in fact the primary data!